# Can't login to other sites

Tags: support, login, linked-accounts

I really would like to join Ask Ubuntu with my account - but it seems impossible to just connect with my existing account (it was my impression my account could login automatically across multiple sites).

And if I try to login with my existing account (Stack Exchange or Google) is says my account not exists, if I try to "recover" my account I get the message : "No users with that email address".

I am really confused. Not very logically to me. What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a separate (but linked) account for each site.

Just sign up with the same OpenID as you used here or on Stack Overflow and a linked account will be created for you.

Comment: Ah, I had to sign up, and THEN the accounts are connected! That worked, i can login and see the ubuntu account on my stackoverflow. Thank you!